# how can I solve the problem related to Npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install, jhipster

I created the app using jhipster online. In order to run it, I need to run the frontend using npm, but when I run the npm install command, it gives the following results [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrENw.png). After i run 'npm audit' i see this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYNfu.png). These are my versions [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHxe7.png)

I tried manually updating dependency versions in json files, but I still get an error when npm start and running the backend

Comment: First, these are only warnings not errors, you are not required to fix them. However, if you want to update some versions, you must run npm install after. Sometimes, blindly updating some dependencies may break your app, so  you must be careful and update one after one and test.